# Требовать указать причину жалобы

Tags: предложение

У меня мало опыта работы с `ajax`, попытался что то самостоятельно сделать, не вышло. Решил задать вопрос, на что получил жалобу (или как это называется) `-1`. Вроде до лампочки, но все равно осадочек остался, да и репутация уходит. Спрашивается за что? Может стоит добавить функционал, типа `поставил "-" укажи причину, если не указал то "-" не ставится`. Ибо в чем смысл? Человек даже в комментах не отписался. Как в будущем мне не допустить такой же ошибки?

P.S.Возможно похожий вопрос задавали, но я не нашел.

[Вот кстати вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1223651/ajax-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-laravel)

Comment: Реагируйте на минусы проще. Тем более один единственный минус это вообще ни о чём ни говорит.

Comment: В вопросе ничего страшного не увидел. Если сильно смущает минус могу плюсом уравновесить для спокойствия.

Comment: Ну а вообще - это сообщество. Каждый имеет возможность голосовать как он считает нужным. Далеко не всегда они(голоса) адекватны. И для того чтобы пользователи не разбрасывались минусами направо и налево специально ввели меру, ограничивающую подобное поведение. А именно: при голосовании против, пользователь отдавший этот голос теряет свою репутацию. Так что здесь Вы в равных условиях.

Comment: @МихаилРебров Теряет только если минус на ответ. Вопрос — за бесплатно.